# How to send nested array in multipart/form-data postman

Tags: json, post, multidimensional-array, postman, multipartform-data

I'm trying to send the following data as multipart/form-data using postman, where the backend is not able to get the "details" array and it's nested parts

```
{
    "name": "any",
    "status": "ACTIVE",
    "slug": "any",
    "member_id": 1,
    "details": {
        "available_countries": {
            "US",
            "CA"
        },
        "available_languages": {
            "en_CA",
            "fr_CA"
        },
        "default_language": "en_CA",
        "prefix": "prefix",
        "time_zone": "EST"
    },
    "enabled" : true,
    "xml" : " <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?> <note> <to>test</to> <from>test</from><heading>test</heading><body>test</body></note> "
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is how you can send nested arrays through form data

**Input:**

```
string:simple text
array[]:X
array[]:Y
array[]:Z
nested_array[available_countries][]:US
nested_array[available_countries][]:CA
nested_array[available_languages][]:EN
nested_array[available_languages][]:FR
```

**Results:**

```
{
    "string": "simple text",
    "array": [
        "X",
        "Y",
        "Z"
    ],
    "nested_array": {
        "available_countries": [
            "US",
            "CA"
        ],
        "available_languages": [
            "EN",
            "FR"
        ]
    }
}
```

**Alternative Solution:**

You can also convert your data to a JSON string, and then parse it in your backend